# How can I print out the actual values of all the variables used by an Ansible playbook?

Tags: variables, ansible

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636087/782011) on StackOverflow suggests using `- debug: var=vars` or `- debug: var=hostvars` to print out all the variables used by an Ansible playbook.

Using `var=hostvars` did not print out all of the variables. But I did get all of the variables printed out when I added the following lines to the top of the main.yml file of the role executed by my playbook:

```
- name: print all variables
  debug:
    var=vars
```

The problem is that the values of the variables printed out are not fully evaluated if they are dependent on the values of other variables. For example, here is a portion of what gets printed out:

```
"env": "dev", 
"rpm_repo": "project-subproject-rpm-{{env}}",
"index_prefix": "project{{ ('') if (env=='prod') else ('_' + env) }}",
"our_server": "{{ ('0.0.0.0') if (env=='dev') else ('192.168.100.200:9997') }}",
```

How can I get Ansible to print out the variables fully evaluated like this?

```
"env": "dev", 
"rpm_repo": "project-subproject-rpm-dev",
"index_prefix": "project_dev",
"our_server": "0.0.0.0",
```

---

EDIT:

After incorporating the `tasks` section in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72369407/782011) into my playbook file and removing the `roles` section, my playbook file looks like the following (where `install-vars.yml` contains some variable definitions):

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - install-vars.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for k in _my_vars %}
          {{ k }}: {{ lookup('vars', k) }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _special_vars:
          - ansible_dependent_role_names
          - ansible_play_batch
          - ansible_play_hosts
          - ansible_play_hosts_all
          - ansible_play_name
          - ansible_play_role_names
          - ansible_role_names
          - environment
          - hostvars
          - play_hosts
          - role_names
        _hostvars: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys() }}"
        _my_vars: "{{ vars.keys()|
                      difference(_hostvars)|
                      difference(_special_vars)|
                      reject('match', '^_.*$')|
                      list|
                      sort }}"
```

When I try to run the playbook, I get this failure:

```
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml 
SSH password: 
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]: 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.100.111]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.100.111]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "lookup plugin (vars) not found"}
to retry, use: --limit @/usr/local/project-directory/installer-1.0.0.0/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.100.111             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: The error is: ``"lookup plugin (vars) not found"``. This plugin was added to Ansible 2.5. What version do you use?

Comment: Try ``{{ k }}: {{ vars[k] }}``

Comment: @VladimirBotka I'm using Ansible 2.2.0.0. When I replaced `{{ k }}: {{ lookup('vars', k) }}` with `{{ k }}: {{ vars[k] }}`, I got it to print out the variables (all on one line with `\n` between them). However, it did not evaluate a variable - for example it printed out `test_var2: {{ test_var1 }}\n`.

Comment: I can't help you with Ansible 2.2. It's pretty outdated don't you think? Install  [supported version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html).

Answer (score 8):

Looking for an answer to the same question, I found the following solution from [this link](https://gryzli.info/2017/12/21/ansible-debug-print-variables/):

```
- name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
  debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
  tags: debug_info
```

Answer (score 4):

The **minimal** playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test_var1: A
    test_var2: "{{ test_var1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: vars
```

**reproduces** the problem you described. For **example**,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep test_var
    test_var1: A
    test_var2: '{{ test_var1 }}'
```

---

Q: ***How can I print out the actual values of all the variables used by an Ansible playbook?***

A: You can get the actual values of the variables when you evaluate them. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test_var1: A
    test_var2: "{{ test_var1 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for k in _my_vars %}
          {{ k }}: {{ lookup('vars', k) }}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        _special_vars:
          - ansible_dependent_role_names
          - ansible_play_batch
          - ansible_play_hosts
          - ansible_play_hosts_all
          - ansible_play_name
          - ansible_play_role_names
          - ansible_role_names
          - environment
          - hostvars
          - play_hosts
          - role_names
        _hostvars: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys() }}"
        _my_vars: "{{ vars.keys()|
                      difference(_hostvars)|
                      difference(_special_vars)|
                      reject('match', '^_.*$')|
                      list|
                      sort }}"
```

gives the evaluated playbook's vars

```yaml
  msg: |-
    test_var1: A
    test_var2: A
```

Comment: I have made the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration! One small improvement: ` msg: "{{ dict(_my_vars| zip(lookup('vars',*_my_vars))) | to_nice_yaml }}"`